# MongoDB: update many not working correctly inside a bulk operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following `updateMany` operation in MongoDB:

```js
myCollection.updateMany({
    _id: {
        $in: myIds,
    }
}, [
    {
        $set: {
            "nested.field": {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: {
                            $objectToArray: "nested.field",
                        },
                        cond: {
                            $gte: [
                                "$$this.k",
                                new Date().toISOString()
                            ],
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Basically what it does is to filter out all the elements inside `$.nested.field` with a key less than the current date.

I am trying to put this inside a bulk op (together with other operations), but I get an error (it works correctly when used with a simple `updateMany`).

```js
const bulkOp = myCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulkOp.find({
    _id: {
        $in: myIds
    },
}).update([
    {
        $set: {
            "nested.field": {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: {
                            $objectToArray: "nested.field",
                        },
                        cond: {
                            $gte: [
                                "$$this.k",
                                new Date().toISOString()
                            ],
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);


await bulkOp.execute();
```

Executing the above I get the following error: `MongoBulkWriteError: $objectToArray requires a document input, found: string`.

How can I make the above working correctly inside a bulk operation?

Comment: For the `$objectToArray`, don't you need a `$` sign in front of `nested.field` (both for the `updateMany` and the bulk update)? Like: `{ $objectToArray: "$nested.field" }`

Comment: You are perfectly right, I forgot the $ sign!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [`$objectToArray`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), you need to provide a field reference with a `$` sign at the beginning, like

```
{ $objectToArray: "$nested.field" }
```

Otherwise, MongoDB will read the value as a string and raise the error that you described.